# Beginner question. Adding multiple colors to object in blender 2.8

Tags: modeling

I can see how to add one base color to an object *Edit mode > material > base color* but how do you add multiple colors or assign each face(s) it's own  color in that same object in 2.8?

Thank you

Comment: The same way you always did in other versions of blender, by selecting the faces you want, creating a new material and assigning the material to the face. Read: [add different materials to different parts of a mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Comment: Thanks, figured it out while I was waiting for a response. 